Can we derive friction from collisions with environment?
I would like to know if friction, that is, the term $-\alpha \dot{x}$ in the equation of a conservative system $\ddot{x} = -\nabla U(x) -\alpha \dot{x}$ can be derived in some way, by assuming elastic collisions with an environment of some sort.
As an example, I computed what happens if a particle (let’s call it the massive particle) moving on a line has to hit small particles (let’s call them environment particles) equally spaced and that do not move before they are hit, with low masses, assuming that each collision of the massive particle with an environment particle is elastic, and that environment particles pass through each other (or just disappear after the collision, since they’re not going to encounter the massive particle afterwards). I found that the massive particle will not be stopped, i.e. will go arbitrarily far, so this cannot model friction, since the massive particle should eventually reach a limit position.
I have then thought of a more complicated model, where the environment particles are moving linearly in random directions, but this is much harder to solve, and I don’t even know how to start.
Therefore, of the only two models I could think of, one was unsuccessful and the other is much too hard.
Friends who are wiser than me told me that it should not be possible to derive a thermodynamical law from conservative systems, but this is not a proof.
My intention is recreational, and I am mainly interested in the math of the problem, so I am looking for either a simple model that can explains friction in the above sense, or a more-or-less formal proof that no such model exists.

I find the run on sentence incomprehensible.

Look at my answer to this previous question ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476883/explaining-friction-using-hamiltonian-mechanics/477036#477036 ) . Does it answer your question?

A resistor that is a dissipative element and is as close to being mechanical friction in electrical circuitry as possible, can be represented by an infinite series of $L$ and $C$, or equivalently a semi-infinite long transmission line. (parallel wires), and there are many such equivalent representations. Any excitations or any portion of it that enters the line is never reflected back despite the fact every element is reactive, lossless, but acting together they are perfect power sinks. Mechanically the line is equivalent to an infinite sequence of coupled massive springs.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 : oh, I had not seen it. Thank you!
